# Mathematicals biology

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Consider the two species competition model given by

$$ \frac{da}{dt }= [λ_1 a /(a+K1)]  - r_{ab}\cdot ab  - da, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$\frac{db}{dt }= [λ_2 b *(1-b/K2)]  - r_{ba}\cdot ab ,  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t>0,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

for two interacting species denoted a=a(t) and b=b(t), with initial conditions a=a0 and b=b0 at t=0. Here λ1, λ2, K1,K2, r_(ab), r_(ba) and d are all positive parameters.
 (a) Describe the biological meaning of each term in the two equations.

=>
A series expansion of 1/(a+K1),  gives

1/(a+K1) ≈  (K1 -a)/ K1 ^2  +  O (a^2)

Now,

da/dt = [λ1 a * (a+K1)/ K1^2]  - r_(ab) ab  - da,

λ1 a  represents the exponential growth of population

da represents the exponential decay of population

λ1  is the growth rate

d is the decay rate

what does  r_(ab) ab represent?

The first term of RHS equation 1: [λ1 a * (a+K1)/ K1^2]  represents logistic growth at a rate λ1 with carrying capacity K1.

db/dt = [λ2 b *(1-b/K2)]  - r_(ba) ab ,

λ2 b  represents the exponential growth of population

λ2  is the growth rate

what does  r_(ba) ab represent?

The first term of RHS equation 2: [λ2 b *(1-b/K2)]  represents logistic growth at a rate λ2 with carrying capacity K2.

Kindly please check my answer.

Comment: Try to improve your question formatting like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical Interspecific competition between two species a and b can be represented by the following equations:

$$\frac{da}{dt} = \lambda_{1}a [1-\frac{a}{k}]$$

This is the logistic population growth model in the absence of competing species b.

Now ,
$$\frac{da}{dt} = \lambda_{1}a [1-\frac{a}{k_{1}} - \frac{\beta_{12}b}{k_{1}}]$$ is the logistic population growth model for a under the presence of species b.  Now we are going to add one more term to the model to represent the decay by exponential decay model.

Exponential decay model is $$\frac{da}{dt} = -\lambda_{d}a$$

Add this term to the original equation, we get
$$\frac{da}{dt} = \lambda_{1}a [1-\frac{a}{k_{1}} - \frac{\beta_{12}b}{k_{1}}] -\lambda_{d}a$$

Now to define each of the term in the above model (ODE).

$\lambda_{1}$ = logistic population growth rate.

$k_1$ - Carrying capacity of species a

**$\beta_{12}b$ - can be thought of as the decrease in growth rate of species "a" due to the presence of species "b"

$\lambda_d$ = exponential decay rate.

Similarly,

$$\frac{db}{dt} = \lambda_{2}b [1-\frac{b}{k_{2}} - \frac{\beta_{21}a}{k_{2}}] $$

Now to define each of the term in the above model (ODE).

$\lambda_{2}$ = logistic population growth rate of b.

$k_2$ - Carrying capacity of species b

**$\beta_{21}a$ - can be thought of as the decrease in growth rate of species "b" due to the presence of species "a".

This is typically the interspecific competition model.  In your original equation, you have  $\beta_{12}$ to be $r_{ab}$

Hope this answers your question.

Good luck

Satish

Comment: Is this MODEL: da/dt = λ1 a[1- (a/k1) - (r_ab ab)/k1] -da  is equal (same) to da/dt = λ1 a / (a+k1) - r_ab ab -da ?

Comment: It is a variation of it.  I am hoping that with some algebraic manipulation, you could derive yours from mine or vice versa. What I have given you is the usual model that is used in physical sciences and competitive model amongst products in marketing.  Let me try to derive from the other when I have free time and let you know

Comment: The McClaurin's series for $$\frac{1}{a+k_{1}} = \frac{1}{k_{1}} - \frac{a}{k_{1}^{2}} + O(a^2) = \frac{1}{k_{1}}[1-\frac{a}{k_{1}}]$$.  I am suspecting that you have missed a $k_1$ in the numerator somewhere. If you had it, the ODE conforms to my model.

Comment: sorry satish, I don't think I have missed k1 in the numerator while expanding series.

Comment: I am talking about missing a $k_1$ in the original ODE for "a".  Your series is correct, I don't dispute it.

Comment: I don't think k1 is missing in the original ODE for a.

Comment: is  r_(ab) ab an interaction term of a and b?
 is  r_(ba) ab an interaction term of a and b?

 r_(ab) can be thought of as the decrease in growth rate of species "a" due to the presence of species "b".
 r_(ba) can be thought of as the decrease in growth rate of species "b" due to the presence of species "a".

 did I define  r_(ab) and  r_(ba) correctly?

Comment: You have defined it correctly the interaction terms.  But $k_1$ still beats me!  Try to see if you can make physical sense of it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know k1 is not appearing in the numerator? but without k1, did I define the biological meaning of each term correctly?

Comment: Please see the edit marked by **.  Also the interaction terms need to be divided by respective K's in the original model.  But convenience sake, you can absorb K and define r as per K.  Note $\beta_{12}$ is defined as the per capita decline ( per individual of species 2).

Comment: thank you . The interaction terms: [r_(ab) ab]/ K1 and       [r_(ba) ab] / K2. may I ask you why and how can I divide the K1 and K2 in th models?

Comment: In general the right-hand side is a collection of various terms that are added or subtracted. When adding or subtracting terms, these should have the same dimension.This rule allows us to deduce, for example, the dimension of the parameter K. Since the ratio a/K in this equation is subtracted from the dimensionless constant 1, both a and K have to have the same dimension. The
term (1− a/K) as a whole is therefore dimensionless.

Comment: r_(ab) ab represents decrease in growth rate of species "a" due to the presence of species "b".                           r_(ba) ab represents decrease in growth rate of species "b" due to the presence of species "a".                          can I define r_(ab) ab and r_(ba) ab by looking at my model?

Comment: (contd..) Because the entire right-hand side should have the dimension of number per unit of time, the dimension of the parameter r is hence per unit time.  Extending the same idea, $\beta_{12}$a has the same dimention as "a".  For this to be dimensionless (as we are subtracting from 1), we are dividing by K which has the same dimension as "a"

Comment: sorry iam little confuse. would you explain me by showing the equations of the model, how and where it applies?

Comment: Your model ultimatley needs to be tested experimentally in the world of pysical sciences.  During which time, what you are able to measure finally decides how you can tweak the model to your convenience.  For example, you can measure r as whole than be able to measure beta individually and lamda individually to combine in the original proposed model then, you can define r in the model without loosing the meaning.  That is how modeling is done to reflect the experimental setup.  I hope you understand.

Comment: you can check out this website for applications of logistic growth model in ecology, yours in biology and other areas. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Comment: thank you very much satish

Comment: If my answer is useful, could you vote if possible

Comment: ok I will vote you. how can I vote you?

Comment: very last qs, I decided to go like this:                       a[λ1(k1-a)/k1^2  - r_ab b] -da.  so,   r_(ab) b can be thought of as the decrease in growth rate of species "a" due to the presence of species "b".    da represents the exponential decay of population. what can I say about this term :         λ1(k1-a)/k1^2.  Thank you

Comment: The term signifies the reasoning that the rate of reproduction of "a" is proportional to both the existing population and the amount of available resources, all else being equal. $\lambda$ is the rate of proportionality and the parameter K is the limiting value of a; the highest value that the population can reach given infinite time.

Comment: sorry are you defining this term:  λ1(k1-a)/k1^2? can you define the above term as a whole?

Comment: The term signifies the growth of a population that starts out with a small number of individuals will ultimately grow to a maximum density, its carrying capacity, which is set by environmental conditions. In other words it is the function that defines the "growth rate" of the species "a" in the absence of competing species "b".  Good luck

Comment: thank you . k1 is the carrying capacity?

Comment: yes.  I am tired now.  You have asked so many questions.  Either I was not thorough in explaining or you really want to understand the model (that is a known model in the literature).  In the process, I  have exhibited my experience in laboratory chemist modeling physical process.:))

Comment: thank you .you are my hero sir.

Comment: You are welcome